# JSTree - How to force user tp only select leafs of the tree

Tags: jquery, jstree

Within my JStree i want the user to only be able to select leafs of the tree. E.g.: Nodes that have no childs. My idea is to bind the select event and manually check whether the selected node has childs and then select/not select the node accordingly.

Is there a simpler way? or is this obvious solution the only one?

Comment: e.g.: Is there an option, that i have overseen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- [Types plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types)
- .is_leaf() for checking if the selected node is a child- 
  node (leaf) or not. Returning false in 'before'-Event will reject 
  selecting the node. See the [jsTree groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/af6e4e66b1eb7609)

In the code.

```
$('#treeID') 
.bind('before.jstree', function(event, data){ 
        switch(data.plugin){ 
                case 'ui': 
                        if(data.inst.is_leaf(data.args[0])){ 
                                return false; 
                        } 
                        break; 
                default: 
                        break; 
        } 
})
```

Comment: Works perfect, you made my day, thanks. And as often, it was in the docs, which i have read ... mostly ... i thought. :)

Comment: For the record, i had to inverse the if expression to  **if (! x.is_leaf())** as i only want the leafs to be selected. e.g. return false if is_leaf is not true.

Comment: I personally 'need' doc with examples otherwise I cannot sometimes figure out how to use it :-)

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work. I want to get only leaf values by using "get_selected" . Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304533/jstree-check-is-selected-nodes-are-leaf-or-make-only-leaves-selectable

Answer (score 8):

2014 - version 3.0.1

```js
$('#jstree').on('activate_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
  if(data.instance.is_leaf(data.node)) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: For me it was "data.inst.is_leaf"

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution For Use CheckBox Plugin (To RadioButton Behavior) Is Here

```
$('#treeview').bind('activate_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
            if (data.instance.get_checked().length > 1) {
                data.instance.uncheck_all();
            }
        });
```

In this jquery.