# JSTree check is selected nodes are leaf or make only leaves selectable

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

I created a jstree as follows

```
$('#js-tree').jstree({
            'core' : {
              'data' : {
                'url' : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/makeTree",
                "plugins" : [ "types", "search"],
                'data' : function (node) {
                  return { 'id' : node.id };
                }
              }
            }
            });
```

I want to check if a selected node is a leaf node while submitting the information -

```
var selectedLeaves = $("#js-tree").jstree("get_selected");
```

But this gives me array of id's only. How do I either use is_leaf method to filter our only leaf nodes from the selected nodes? 
I referred to this post - 
[Force user to select only leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502697/jstree-how-to-force-user-tp-only-select-leafs-of-the-tree)
This solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution on my own using an argument to the `get_selected` api to filter out the leaves from the folders -

```
var nodes = $("#js-tree").jstree(true).get_selected("full", true);
$.each(nodes,function(i, node){
  if(node.children.length >0){
    console.log("not leaf");
  }
  else{
    console.log("leaf");
  }  
});
```

If you have a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
var res = jQuery.jstree.reference('#js-tree').get_json('#', { flat: true });
                var cnt = 0;
                for (var i = 0, j = res.length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (res[i].parent !== '#') {
                        cnt++;
                    }
                }
```

cnt is the ourput